# UIDatePicker.Mode.countDownTimer: can I display minutes only five by five?

Tags: ios, uikit, uidatepicker

Is it possible to use a `UIDatePicker` with `.datePickerMode = .countDownTimer`, but setting minutes five by five? I mean, having only `0, 5, 10, 15...` as possible values for the minutes?

Or do I need to write my own `UIPickerView` for this?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should set timeInterval: 5.

> The interval is measured seconds so for it to perform like a standard
> clock we should set this argument to 1. if you want to count 5 by 5 second. You shal pass to 5 as a parameter.

```
func runTimer() { 
     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self,   selector: (#selector(TimeViewController.updateTime)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```